# understanding Back stack concept in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I am trying to Understand what is a back stack concept in Android

*What i have tried to learn*: I went through the [Developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html)

- what i could learn is that, back stack is the one concept that
  differs fragment lifecycle from regular activity life cycle
- When the activity is placed to back-stack of activities, the user can
  navigate back to previous activity by just pressing the back button

---

**My question**::

- Does this mean i can add `activity1`- - `activity2`- -`activity3`
  .... then `activity3` is at top of the back stack so if i press back
  button .... I go from `activity3` - - to - - `activity2` ...... then
  again i go from `activity2` - - `activity1` finally
- What more can i add for my learning ?

**[EDIT]**

- Also i remember using finish() to navigate back in regular activity
  life cycle
- Does this mean that regular activity life cycle also has back stack
  ..... if no ?
- How different is back stack from using a finish() in regular activity
  life cycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read this detailed [Documentation (Developer Site)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) and this [Presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack) 
Along with that there are many other things that you can do with `Back Stack`, for example:

1. [How to find back stack activities in an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992563/how-to-find-back-stack-activities-in-an-android-application)
2. [How to Control Android back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142936/how-to-controll-android-back-stack)

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

[Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and `Back Stack` are 2 different entities.

When Activity's `finish()` is called, the Activity is `Stopped()` and removed from the `Back Stack`.
 The `Back Stack` is updated in conjunction with the Activity's Life Cycle.
Like when a new `Activity` is started, the `Back Stack` is updated and the current `Activity` is stacked at the Top and when an `Activity` is finished, the `Back Stack` is updated again and the former Activity is removed from it.

Comment: [+1] - for good information....... Also wanted to know if the user navigates from one activity to another and that first activity is not in back-stack then it is automatically added for the back-stack ?

Comment: Thanks!, if the user is navigating back and at that time there are no Activities (of the current Application) in the `Back Stack` then the user will be navigated to the Home Screen.

Comment: OR in other case, if your App is launched via Web-Service and there was already some app running in the Foreground at that time, then in the Empty `Back Stack` scenario the user will be navigated to the other App's Activity that was previously in the Foreground.

Comment: Thanks again .... i have added few more information on question.... Please have a look and. can you edit & add more information to your answer